# C# cannot convert `System.Delegate' expression to type `PowellMethod.fcn_delegate'

Tags: c#, delegates

I'am trying to provide a C# function compiled at run time to a class.

i get following error:
Argument `#1' cannot convert`System.Delegate' expression to type `PowellMethod.fcn_delegate'

In Main class.css

```
    public delegate void fcn_delegate(int n, double[] x, double[] f, int iflag);
static void Main()
{

    PowellMethod powell = new PowellMethod();

    MethodInfo function = CreateFunction(StringFunction); // the function contents defined as a string
    var betterFunction = (Func<int, double[], double[], int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int, double[], double[], int>), function);

    Delegate test = (fcn_delegate) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(fcn_delegate), function);

    //powell.dnsqe_nice(betterFunction,0, x,tol,bounds,ref fnorm,ref info);
    powell.dnsqe_nice(test,0, x,tol,bounds,ref fnorm,ref info);


}

public static MethodInfo CreateFunction(string function)
{
    string code = @"
            using System;

            namespace UserFunctions
            {                
                public class BinaryFunction
                {                
                    public static void Function(int n, double[] x, double[] f, int iflag)
                    {
                        func_xy;
                    }
                }
            }
        ";

    string finalCode = code.Replace("func_xy", function);

    CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
    CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(new CompilerParameters(), finalCode);

    Type binaryFunction = results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("UserFunctions.BinaryFunction");
    return binaryFunction.GetMethod("Function");
}
```

}

In PowellMethod.css

```
public delegate void fcn_delegate(int n, double[] x, double[] f, int iflag);

public void dnsqe_nice(fcn_delegate fcn, int jac,  double[] x, double tol, double[,] bounds, ref double fnorm,ref  string info)
    {
// code .. 
}
```

i tried both (test or better function).
What is this System.Delegate and why is it different from the delegate define in PowellMethod ??

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

OK, i managed to find the answer

the solution is

```
PowellMethod.fcn_delegate betterFunction = (PowellMethod.fcn_delegate)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(PowellMethod.fcn_delegate), function);
```

and it works fine